# Trying to capture value of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a select box and I'm trying to get value of the selected option. I get error **Property 'value' of object # is not a function**

HTML:

```
    <select id="my_SiteUsers" style="width:350px;" onchange="RefreshGroupLists()">
<option  
     value="i:0#.w|itun\akondruss_fg">Alex</option>
<option value="i:0#.w|itun\allepage_fg">Alex</option>
</select>
```

[image]

JS:

```
  var e = document.getElementById("my_SiteUsers");
  var user = e.value();
  alert(user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is not a function, it's a property of the DOM node :

```
var e = document.getElementById("my_SiteUsers");
var user = e.value;
alert(user);
```

or with jQuery:

```
var user = $('#my_SiteUsers').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's .val(), like many jq functions it will be (possibly) much easier than through js.

```
// Get the value from a dropdown select
$( "select.foo option:selected").val();
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/

edit-- looks like the above solution solved it more easily :)